# Forcing parsing of request with no Content-Type with Rest Framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-1.7

I'm writing a Rest Framework view for receiving a JSON POST request. However, the incoming request has no Content-Type header (valid HTTP), and as [documented](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests), Rest Framework throws an `UnsupportedMediaType` and returns a `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

**I do not control the client.** How can I force the request to processed with `JSONParser` despite no declared content type? (perhaps I can access the underlying request before processing by the parsers?)

Here's is my current (simple) view:

```
class Callback(APIView):
    # this doesn't help
    # parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # ...operate on request.DATA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at writing a custom content negotiation class.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/content-negotiation#custom-content-negotiation

You'll want to base it on the default implementation, but returning `JSONParser` if nothing else matches.